# Count number of times where two conditions are met in each row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to VBA, and I don't have much knowledge about how to set up my own formulas.

I have a spreadsheet where I have a column with different fill colours to indicate the status of the referral (active, maybe, inactive), and the name of the person who sees the client in another column. I'm trying to set up a formula that tells me how many active/maybe/inactive referrals each staff member has, and then displays that data in a table. I've attached an sample image that shows what I'm talking about with x, y, and z representing different staff members.

I could change the first column to say active/maybe/inactive, but I'd like to keep with the colour coding if possible.

[image: Sample Table]

Currently, I have some code that allows me to count the number of cells have a certain colour, and I'm hoping I can have some help building on what I have.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Public Function CountByColor(rng As Range, Red As Long, Green As Long, Blue As Long) As Long

    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    
    For Each rngCell In rng
        If rngCell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red, Green, Blue) Then
            lCount = lCount + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    CountByColor = lCount
    
End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My advice: Write the status into the cell. You can use conditional formatting to set the colors, and if you don't want to see the text, format the font to have the same color as the background.

Comment: That's a good work-around. It does work, but I'd prefer if I didn't have to type the status into the cell as I find it easier to just change the fill colour. If I created a formula that recognizes the fill colour, and nested it in a COUNTIFS formula, would that work? For example COUNTIFS(B1:B10, FORMULA(colour value), C1:C10, "X").

Comment: If you say up data validation (really, even if you don't), you can just select from a drop down, or by pressing `Alt+Enter`. And with data validation, you can make sure someone's not entering invalid values (or selecting a slightly different color).

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `rng` should be two columns range. eg. =CountByColor(A1:B10,"X",255,0,0)

Please be aware that there is a side effect: the formula won't update if the color of the first column changes.

```vb
Public Function CountByColor(rng As Range, sKey As Variant, _
    Red As Long, Green As Long, Blue As Long) As Long
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Application.Volatile
    If rng.Columns.Count <> 2 Then
        CountByColor = 99999
    Else
        For Each rngCell In rng.Columns(1).Cells
            If rngCell.Interior.Color = RGB(Red, Green, Blue) _
                And rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = sKey Then
                lCount = lCount + 1
            End If
        Next
        CountByColor = lCount
    End If
End Function
```

There is a workaround option which is close to your expected result. Users have to click any cells in column A `AFTER` color change. It tiggers `Selection_Change` to update the last cell (you could use any cell as a trigger) on worksheet. Then it tigger recalculation.

**Note:** `UsedRange` doesn't work as normal because the last cell is used as a trigger cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Application.Intersect(Target, Columns(1))
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        With Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, Me.Columns.Count)
            .Value = Not .Value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried that and it works, but it won't update the total if I change the fill color. It only updates if I retype "Y".

Comment: Formulas are recalculated when cells change, but the color change doesn't count. `Application.Volatile` isn't helpful for it. Is it acceptable if color format of the first column comes from conditional format.

Comment: Would a force calculation work if the target intersects with the A-column in the worksheet_selectionchange event?

Comment: `Selection_Change` will not really work es it is triggered when the cell is selected - at this time the color is not changed. Recalculation would happen when another cell is selected - but for example if the user changes the sheet, it would not be triggered at all.

Comment: As FunThomas comment, Selection_Change is triggered before color change. There is a workaround option which is close to your expected result. Users have to click a cell in column A `AFTER` color change.